# C: On passing pointer having array to a function there is run time error. Why?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, function-pointers

```
int add_up (int *a, int num_elements);

int main() 
{
  int orders[5] = {100, 220, 37, 16, 98};
  int *p;
  p=&orders[0];

  printf("Total orders is %d\n", add_up(*p, 5));
```

> here If I pass pointer what is the problem? As pointer will point to no. 100 value. As 100 is an int value which will go to int *a. And the program should go well right?
>   Edit 1: If I give p here in place of *p then will it be address of orders[0] and not value 100 right?
>    But function int *a wants value 100 right. Correct me if I am wrong in this concept and thanks.

```
  return 0;
}

int add_up (int *a, int num_elements) 
{
  int total = 0;
  int k;

  for (k = 0; k < num_elements; k++) 
  {
    total += a[k];
  }
  return (total);
}
```

Comment: Take the compiler's warning(s) serious.

Comment: What compiler are you using? If you didn't get any warnings, you need to switch to a better compiler ASAP. If you did get warnings, you should have read and headed them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with the following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int add_up (int *a, int num_elements);

int main() 
{
  int orders[5] = {100, 220, 37, 16, 98};
  int *p;
  p=&orders[0];

  printf("Total orders is %d\n", add_up(p, 5)); 
  return 0;
}

int add_up (int *a, int num_elements) 
{
  int total = 0;
  int k;

  for (k = 0; k < num_elements; k++) 
  {
    total += a[k];
  }
  return (total);
}
```

You have forgotten to include 2 headers and `add_up(*p, 5)` and remove the `*`.

Comment: Why should I add  p and not *p as int *a is a pointer. p gives address. *p gives value of the array. Correct me if I am wrong in some way. Thanks.

Comment: your prototype of add_up function is ` int add_up (int *a, int num_elements) ` so the first parameter is pointer of type integer . 
p is already pointer
 If you write add_up(*p,5) you sendn't adress of first element of 'orders' tab but the value of variable pointed by p , which means you send the value 100 

*p => i want to get the value pointed by p 

p=> i want to get the value of p , so adress of variable pointed by p